# Can I write Component inside Component in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have come across many sources which talk about how to do `Component` nesting. However, whenever I try to create a `Component` inside another `Component` my code fails.

```
class parent extends React.Component{
    class child extends React.Component{
        render(){
            return <div><h1>Hiiii</h1></div>;
        }
    }
    render(){
        return <div><DEF /></div>;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you possibly trying to achieve by doing this? You can have them written separately in same file and use it the way you want in terms of rendering.

Comment: This is not valid javascript

Comment: @Axnyff  It is React.js code.

Comment: @RishikeshDhokare Actually,When we does not use redux, and want to write complex code then in some condition I want to use component inside component. I heard from some people that it's possible.However, i don't know how.

Comment: Try it here: https://babeljs.io/repl/, you'll get a syntax error. This is not valid javascript, even if you'd compile the jsx

Comment: Do you want to render a component with a condition ?

Comment: @MayankBansal No. My Objective is to keep common states between parent and child in parent, and states which are related to child in child

Comment: "Your scientists were so preoccupied with whether or not they could, they didn’t stop to think if they should." - Dr Ian Malcolm, Jurassic Park

Comment: Any update on this? Now we prefer functional components and we can define one component inside another. But is it good to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comoponent nesting means rendering react components inside other components. Like

```
<ParentComponent property={value}>
    <div>
        <ChildComponent />
        ...
    </div>
</ParentComponent>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can't do that. You can do this on the same file (not same component)

```
class DEF extends Component {
  render() {
   return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hiiii</h1>
    </div>
    );
 }
}

export default class ABC extends Component {
  render() {
       return (
       <div>
           <DEF />
       </div>
       );
   }
}
```

Comment: 1. you can not have 2 default exports in the same file
2. you need to define DEF before ABC

Comment: You're right. I copy/pasted the code and didn't change that.

Answer (score 6):

You can't define class inside another class and I don't see why you would want to.

In React you can define Components in two ways: a stateful component (class) or a functional component (function). Stateful components should only be used when you need to manage state locally.

You can do something like:

```
export default class MyStatefulComponent extends Component() {
  render() {
    return (
      <div><MyFunctionalComponent {...this.props} /></div>
    )
  }
}

function MyFunctionalComponent(props) {
  return <h1>I am functional</h1>
}
```

I have used the spread operator to pass on the props from the stateful to the functional component, but you should probably pass the individual props as needed..

Comment: As for why you'd want to, let's say the subcomponent (MyFunctionalComponent) needed to use a function from MyStatefulComponent and you didn't want to always have to pass it in as a prop

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can achieve what you are trying to do.

```
class ABC extends React.Component {

  render() {
    class DEF extends React.Component {
       render() {
       return (
           <div>
               <h1>Hiiii</h1>
           </div>
         );
        }
    }
     return (
      <div>
        <DEF />
      </div>
      );
   }
 }
```

Comment: Your answer is right. However, answer ticked by me is more conceptually right.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can just define component as a static property of other component

```
class Test extends Component {
 static SubTest=props=><div>SubTet</div>
 render(){
  return(
   <div>Test component</div>
   )
 }

<Test />
<test.SubTest />
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks