# Using React, is it possible to define a component inside the definition of another component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

*(this question differs to 'is it possible to use a component inside another', this question is 'can I define a component inside the definition of another', it is not a duplicate of 'Can I write Component inside Component in React?')*

Is it possible to define a component inside the definition of another component?  This way I can use the props of the outside component in the inner component.  It would keep the code more concise. Something like the following...

```
class AComponent extends Component {
    CustomButton = (props) => {
        let { disabled, ...otherProps } = props // <-- props of the inner component
        const {isDisabled, currentClassName} = this.props // <-- props of the main component

        return (
            <button
                className={className}
                disabled={isDisabled}
                {...otherProps}>
            </button>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <CustomButton>Add something</CustomButton>
                <CustomButton>Delete something</CustomButton>
                <CustomButton>Edit</CustomButton>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

If the custom button was defined on its own (the usual way of defining components) I would have to do something like below which is ok but more verbose and less dry as I repeat the definition of {...buttonProps} for each component

```
let buttonProps = { 
        className: this.props.currentClassName,
        disabled: this.props.disabled
}

return (
    <div>
        <button {...buttonProps}>Add something</button>
        <button {...buttonProps}>Delete something</button>
        <button {...buttonProps}>Edit</button>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I write Component inside Component in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48543628/can-i-write-component-inside-component-in-react)

Comment: No, I don't think so, my question is about defining a component inside another, not rendering or using one component inside another.  It may not be possible in React...I'm trying to discover the boundaries of what is possible :-)  Many thanks for your input though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! I needed to define the function component in the render method...which makes sense

```
class AComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        const ButtonLocal = (props) => {
            const {isDisabled, currentClassName} = this.props

            return (
                <Button 
                    disabled={isDisabled} 
                    className={currentClassName} 
                    {...buttonProps}>
                </Button>
            )
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <ButtonLocal>Add something</ButtonLocal>
                <ButtonLocal>Delete something</ButtonLocal>
                <ButtonLocal>Edit</ButtonLocal>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Here in this example ButtonLocal component unmounts and remounts every time the render is called. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

While yes, it's possible to define one function component inside another function component, this is not recommended.

Referring to the ReactJs docs:
[reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)
[reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Most, if not all, examples show child components being defined *outside* of the parent component.

Defining a component inside another will cause the child component to be re-created on mount and unmount of the parent, which could cause unexpected behavior if the child is using props from the parent, and cannot handle if those props are suddenly undefined.

It's best to define components separately.

Answer (score -1):

Very much possible to add components inside a parent component. Consider following example:

```
<ParentComponent style={styles}>
  <ChildComponent style={styles} {...props} />
</ParentComponent>
```

Comment: Many thanks Pir for your input, there is a difference here, this is answering 'can I use one component inside another?'.  My question is 'can I define one component inside the definition of another?'