# Losing state between renders if component is defined in another component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, closures, use-state

codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-haze-v01wv?file=/src/App.js

I have a Users component which (when simplified) looks something like this:

```
const Users = () => {
  const [toastOpen, setToastOpen] = useState(false)

  // functions to handle toast closing
  return (
   <EditUser />
   <Toast />
  )
}

const EditUser = () => {
  [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchedUser = await fetchUser()
    setUser(fetchedUser)
  }, [])

  // this approach results in UserForm's username resetting when the toast closes
  const Content = () => {
    if (user) return <UserForm user={user} />
    else return <div>Loading...</div>
  }
  return <Content />

  // if I do this instead, everything's fine
  return (
    <div>
    {
      user ? <UserForm user={user} /> : <div>Loading...</div>
    }
    </div>
  )
}

const UserForm = ({ user }) => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState(user.name)

  return <input value={username}, onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)} />
}
```

While viewing the UserForm page while a Toast is still open, the UserForm state is reset when the Toast closes.

I've figured out that the issue is the `Content` component defined inside of `EditUser`, but I'm not quite clear on why this is an issue. I'd love a walkthrough of what's happening under React's hood here, and what happens in a "happy path"

Comment: Can you share the full code of Users component

Comment: Related: [Can I write Component inside Component in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48543628/can-i-write-component-inside-component-in-react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `Content` inside `EditUser` component which we never do with React Components, because in this situtaion, `Content` will be **re-created** every time the `EditUser` is **re-rendered**. (surely, EditUser is going to be re-rendered few/many times).

So, a re-created `Content` component means the old `Content` will be destroyed (unmounted) and the new `Content` will be mounted.

That's why it is be being mounted many times and hence **resetting** the *state values* to initial values.

So, the solution is to just define it (Content) outside - **not inside any other react component**.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. So when React goes to render `<Content />`, is this what happens:
"I must render a Content component. The Content function is different from the last time I rendered this Component, so I must unmount the previous Content component and recreate one from scratch"?

Comment: Exactly! That's correct. And as it renders a **new** component, it sets up new state and all from scratch, and it loses all previous state values. I have not tried it, but i guess, we can **keep** a component definition inside a component and use **useCallback** hook to prevent it from getting **re-created**, but it would be doing a simple thing in a complex way, so not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit was EditUser's `Content` function, which predictably returns a brand new instance of  each time it's called.

Comment: Yes. It should not be defined inside a Component.

Comment: Could you explain why? I have a feeling it has something to do with creating a new closure (which creates a new component with new state every time), but I'm really fuzzy on the details. I'd love a quick walkthrough on what happens in this fail case, and in a "correct" case.