# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function when doing compose on ReactJS HOC

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hoc

I have a component where I try to compose (imported from "compose-function" library) as below;

```
export function MyRoute() {
  let MyGridWithData = compose(
    withRouter,
    withTranslation("translations"),
    withMyApi()
  )(MyGrid);
  return <MyGridWithData />;
}
```

However, for some reason, I am seeing the below error;

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
```

The error is pointed on the line ; let MyGridWithData = compose(...)

Also, while withRouter & withTranslation are standard hooks, withMyApi is defined as below (it is a HOF basically);

```
export function withMyApi() {
  // Extra function wrapper 
  return function(WrappedComponent) {
    class MyApiUrls extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      }

      render() {
        return <WrappedComponent api={this.api} {...this.props} />;
      }
    }
    return MyApiUrls;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All looks correct except; probably you are incorrectly importing [compose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compose-function) function.

It is a default export, not a named one. So, the correct way to import is:

```
import compose from 'compose-function';
```

---

Side note: [Don’t Use HOCs Inside the render Method](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#dont-use-hocs-inside-the-render-method) as it similar to [re-creating a component at every re-render](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66571922/2873538). So, You should write it as:

```
const MyGridWithData = compose(
    withRouter,
    withTranslation("translations"),
    withMyApi()
  )(MyGrid);

export function MyRoute() {
  // more code if any
  return <MyGridWithData />;
}
```

Comment: Oh...my bad !! So sorry...such a silly thing to do!! Thanks for pointing that out !

Comment: Of course, I remember...How can I forget such a wonderful person :)