# What's the difference between functions that render JSX vs. declaring components inside another component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, react-functional-component

Is this an anti-pattern?

```
export function Todo() {
    ...

    const renderItem = (item) => (
        item.done
            ? <strike>{item.text}</strike>
            : <span>{item.text}</span>
    );

    return (
        <ul>
            {items.map((item) => <li>renderItems(item)</li>)}
        </ul>
    );
}
```

What's the difference between rendering items like that, as compared to making an Item component inside Todo, such as this:

```
export function Todo() {
    ...

    const Item = (props) => (
        props.item.done
            ? <strike>{item.text}</strike>
            : <span>{item.text}</span>
    );

    return (
        <ul>
            {items.map((item) => <li><Item item={item} /></li>)}
        </ul>
    );
}
```

EDIT:

What about creating components/render functions locally, that are called once?

```
export function SomeForm(props) {
    const renderButton = (isComplete) => (
        isComplete
            ? <button>Submit</button>
            : <button disabled>Please complete</button>
    );

    return (
        <form>
            <input />
            {renderButton(props.isDone)}
        </form>
    );
}
```

Comment: [Losing state between renders if component is defined in another component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66571922/2873538)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it an anti-pattern to define a function component inside the render() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52372040/is-it-an-anti-pattern-to-define-a-function-component-inside-the-render-functio)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Beforehand lets fix the examples into a valid code:

```
// #1
export function Todo({items}) {
  const renderItem = (item) =>
    item.done ? <strike>{item.text}</strike> : <span>{item.text}</span>;

  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <li key={item.id}>{renderItems(item)}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

// #2
export function Todo({items}) {
  const Item = (props) =>
    props.item.done ? <strike>{item.text}</strike> : <span>{item.text}</span>;

  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <li key={item.id}>
          <Item item={item} />
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Back to the question, **Yes** those are anti-patterns.

#### Why it's an anti-pattern?

In both examples, you will rerender the item even though there wasn't any visual change.

The reason for it because on every render, you recreate both function (`renderItem`) and function component (`Item`).

#### What you want

Instead, you want to let React do the [Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper) process, for it you need render a static tree as much as possible.

The easiest solution is just move the function/function component, to the outer scope or inlining the logic into the tree itself.

```
const renderItem = (item) => (...)
const Item = (props) => (...)

export function Todo({ items }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <li key={item.id}>
          (item.done ? <strike>{item.text}</strike>:<span>{item.text}</span>)
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

---

> What's the difference between rendering items like that

`renderItem` is just a function returning JSX, `Item` is a React component, therefore its state is registered to the React tree ("just a function" can't hold its own state).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the difference between "just a function" and a react component! I understand that this is especially inefficient when rendering a list of sorts, but what if I am rendering something just once. Is creating a "render" function or a local component still an anti-pattern then? I added (a rather contrived) example in the edit.

Comment: Your edits are the same examples, still anti pattern