# React wrapper component not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using [React-Dropzone](https://react-dropzone.js.org/) and following the first example on the website:

```
function MyDropzone() {
  const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive } = useDropzone({ onDrop });

  return (
    <div {...getRootProps()}>
      <input {...getInputProps()} />
      Hello
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to create a wrapper class like this:

```
function MyDropzone() {
  const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive } = useDropzone({ onDrop });

  function Wrapper({ children }) {
    return (
      <div {...getRootProps()}>
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  }

  return <Wrapper>Hello</Wrapper>;
}
```

but when I do this, react-dropzone stops working. When I click the element, nothing happens whereas on the first example it works fine. Isn't this how wrapper components work or am I missing something?

---

Comment: [You should not define a component inside a component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66571922/2873538).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```
function Wrapper({ children }) {
  const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive } = useDropzone({ onDrop });
  return (
    <div {...getRootProps()}>
      <input {...getInputProps()} />
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}

function MyDropzone() {
  return <Wrapper>Hello</Wrapper>;
}
```

The reason behind this is if you define Wrapper inside MyDropzone functional component, it will define new component everytime you render. Which means if will rerendered every render.

Comment: One issue I have with this is I want to use the useDropzone hook in both the Wrapper component and the MyDropzone component. Initializing it in both makes it stop working. Any suggestions on how to overcome this?